# SwiftUI misleading error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I keep getting the 'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' on line 83 .offset(x: 150, y:7). If I wrap the number in CGFloat() the same error just appears elsewhere. I know it's something to do with the control flow in my program but I can't identify where. Pls help.

This is my code for DateTracking.swift screen (where I'm getting the error).

```
struct DateTracking: View {

    @State var recipes: [Recipe] = getRecipes()
    @State var filterRecipesBy: String = ""
    @State private var searchTerm: String = ""
    @State var sortedNames: [Item] =  getItemsSortedByNames()
    @State var sortedDays: [Item] =  getItemsSortedByDaysLeft()
    @State var arraySelection: Int = 0
    @State var sortBySelected: Bool = false
    @State var recipesShown: Bool = false
    @State var buttonShown: Bool = true


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

            ZStack{


                VStack{

                    SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)



                    if(self.arraySelection == 0){
                        QGrid(sortedDays.filter {
                                    self.searchTerm.isEmpty ? true :
                                        $0.imageName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchTerm)
                                }, columns: 3) { item in


                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.filterRecipesBy = item.imageName
                                        recipesShown.toggle()
                                    }){
                                        ListItem(imageName: item.imageName, daysLeft: item.daysLeft, redBackground: item.redBackground )
                                    }



                                }
                                //.background(Color(red: 239 / 255, green: 239 / 255, blue: 239 / 255))
                            }

                    if(self.arraySelection == 1){
                        QGrid(sortedNames.filter {
                                    self.searchTerm.isEmpty ? true :
                                        $0.imageName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchTerm)
                                }, columns: 3) { item in

                                    ListItem(imageName: item.imageName, daysLeft: item.daysLeft, redBackground: item.redBackground )

                                }
                            //.background(Color(red: 239 / 255, green: 239 / 255, blue: 239 / 255))
                        }

                    }



                if (self.sortBySelected == true){
                    VStack{

                        Button(action: {
                            self.sortBySelected.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Done")

                        }
                        .offset(x: 150, y: 7)

                        Picker(selection: self.$arraySelection, label:
                            Text("Picker Name")){
                            Text("Expiry Date").tag(0)
                            Text("Names").tag(1)

                        }
                        .labelsHidden()


                    }
                    .frame(width:375)
                    .background(Color(red: 239 / 255, green: 239 / 255, blue: 239 / 255))
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 140)


                }

                if (self.recipesShown == true){
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {

                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {self.recipesShown.toggle()
                            }){
                                Cross()
                            }
                            .offset(x: -70, y: 11)
                            Text(verbatim: "Recipes You Can Cook")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding(.top)
                                .offset(x: -50, y: 5)
                        }


                        RecipesVertical(recipes: self.recipes.filter($0.ingredients.contains(filterRecipesBy)))
                            .padding(.leading)

                            //.offset(x: 0, y: 140)
                    }
                    .frame(width:375, height:310, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.white)

                }

               /* if(buttonShown == true){
                    Button(action: {self.recipesShown = true
                        self.buttonShown = false
                    }){
                        Image("floatingrecipebutton")
                        .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 85, height: 85)
                            .shadow(radius: 10)

                                   }
                                       .offset(x: 125, y:200)
                }
               */





            }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Date Tracking"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:

                HStack{

                    Button(action: {
                        self.sortBySelected.toggle()
                        }){
                        Text("Sort by")
                    }

                        }


            )


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a "why isn't this code working" question. It requires a MCVE. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) There's a lot of code here and it won't compile for responders because it includes lots of types and functions that we don't have. Reduce this down to the smallest code that produces the problem (I suspect when you do that, you'll also find your answer).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you can't assign an Int to a CGFloat without specifically cast.

In this case, instead of writing `1` you can change to `1.0`. That'll work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795316/swift-compiler-error-int-is-not-convertible-to-cgfloat

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error code you are getting is vague here, if you try to solve the GCFloat then Xcode will bring some other similar problem.

Problem might be with you syntax (it was for me once), here is the another youtube video link I am sharing where the actual problem is different and Xcode show the similar error.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLSzgZtOpG8&list=PLMRqhzcHGw1Z-lZaaun3A3mV9PbEfHANI&index=8

Play the video around 22:30, you will the similar GCFloat error, while actual problem is with VStack.